# Subquery only returns one value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this query.

```
SELECT 
  d.gid, d.channel_id
FROM channels, (
  SELECT 
      gigs.id as gid, gigs.channel_id
    FROM gigs
    ORDER BY gigs.id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) as d
WHERE d.channel_id = channels.id
LIMIT 10
```

I was hoping to get one `gid` for each `channels.id`, but instead it only returns one column. Why is that?

Gigs table

```
+---------+------------+
| id      | channel_id |
+---------+------------+
| 150661  | 6          |
| 745797  | 6          |
| 483996  | 6          |
| 3407209 | 6          |
| 1175022 | 5          |
| 3238459 | 6          |
| 711413  | 5          |
| 524758  | 5          |
| 154764  | 5          |
| 1594779 | 5          |
| 1659091 | 2          |
| 1086768 | 6          |
| 1161320 | 8          |
| 467394  | 5          |
| 2877040 | 8          |
| 2705821 | 6          |
| 1881747 | 5          |
| 901902  | 1          |
| 143322  | 6          |
| 671658  | 1          |
+---------+------------+
```

Channels table

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
| 6  |
| 7  |
| 8  |
| 9  |
| 10 |
+----+
```

Comment: can you provide sample records on your question? :D

Comment: Sure. I added a simpler query and some example data

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

```
SELECT  a.id, b.max_ID
FROM    channels a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT channel_ID, MAX(id) max_ID
            FROM gigs
            GROUP BY channel_ID
        ) b ON a.id = b.channel_ID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f2e1/1)

basically, I used `INNER JOIN` to show only id from `channels` table that has atleast on record on `gigs` table. If you want to show list even if there is no match on `gigs` table then you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: Same thing, the query only returns one result, not 10.

Comment: oh i forget to mention that you need to remove the `GROUP BY` clause since you did not aggregate any of the columns.

Comment: It takes about 8 seconds to run, which is a bit slow. Here is the explain output. https://gist.github.com/8dcf4eeb86dbb1aa5414

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM Gigs WHERE channel_id = c.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) As GigID

FROM channels c
```

Comment: That will only work if i only want `gigs.id`. I need both `gigs.id` and `gigs.channel_id`, that's why I'm using a inner select.